# About the selection of progressive view

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, xcode5.1

I add a progressive view in the story board, I found it is very hard to select this view. How do you solve this kind of problem when using Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

You can always reach to the Document Outline, which provides the full view hierarchy and you have an option to select the view or ctrl-drag any connections from there.